# Measurable cardinals: non-trivial two-valued measures

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

while doing some exercises about measurable cardinals, I got stuck on this one:

If $κ$ is the minimal
cardinal that carries a non-trivial two-valued measure, then how can one prove that $κ$ is measurable?

I do not really have an idea on how to approach this, and am grateful for help.

Comment: How about $A\in \mathcal{U}\iff \mu (A) = 1$ ?

Comment: @Max I think the question is about how to prove the measure is $\kappa$-additive. The difference between encoding the measure as a subset of $\mathcal P(\kappa)$ or as a function $\mu:\mathcal P(\kappa)\to\{0,1\}$ is insignificant.

Comment: What properties do you have to prove to show that $\kappa$ is measurable? Which ones have you done, and which are you stuck on?

Comment: Suppose that, for some cardinal $\lambda\lt\kappa$, there are $\lambda$ null sets whose union has measure $1$. Can you use that to show that $\lambda$ carries a non-trivial two-valued measure?

Comment: @bof : you're right, I had misread the question !

Comment: @bof Yes, I have to show $κ$-additivity of the measure (well and uncountable), and it would follow that $κ$ is measurable. I don't know how to approach the $κ$-additivity from a 2-valued measure...In the case you stated, if the union has measure 1, wouldn't the sum of the individual measures also have to be 1? But the sets are all nullsets...how do you mean this?

Comment: You have to prove that the measure is $\kappa$-additive, right? How do you define "$\kappa$-additive? How would you state the negation? Assume for a contradiction that $\kappa$-additivity fails — what does that mean? I guessed it would mean that for some $\lambda\lt\kappa$ there is a collection of $\lambda$ sets of measure $0$ whose union has measure $1$, but apparently I guessed wrong. So please explain it to me.

Comment: @bof Oh, yes sorry then you were right. I didn't catch that you were aiming for a contradiction. I tried what you said, but I couldn't arrive at a contradiction...I think it will be about the minimality of $κ$, but I didn't find it yet...

Comment: Let $\mu$ be a non-trivial two-valued measure on $\kappa$ and assume for a contradiction that $\mu$ is not $\kappa$-additive, so there is a cardinal $\lambda\lt\kappa$ and a family $(A_\xi,\ \xi\in\lambda)$ of subsets of $\kappa$ such that $\mu(A_\xi)=0$ for each $\xi\in\lambda$ while $\mu(\bigcup_{\xi\in\lambda}A_\xi)=1$. Now let's try something wild and crazy. Let's define a function $\nu:\mathcal P(\lambda)\to\{0,1\}$ by $$\nu(X)=\mu\left(\bigcup_{\xi\in X}A_\xi\right).$$ I wonder what properties $\nu$ has.

Comment: @bof. I decided to turn your last comment into an answer. (I already knew this stuff.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m:P(k)\to \{0,1\}$ be a non-trivial  measure. Let $I=m^{-1}\{0\}.$

Suppose there exists cardinal $j$ with $\omega <j<k$ and $A=\{A_x:x<j\}\subset m^{-1}\{0\}$ such that $m(\cup A)=1.$

Let  $i$ be the least such $j.$

Let $B=\{A_x\setminus \cup_{y<x}A_y: y\in i\}\setminus \{\emptyset\}.$ Then $m(\cup B)=1$ and $B\subset m^{-1}\{0\}.$  Now $B$ is a pair-wise disjoint family and $\emptyset \not \in B,$ and by the minimality of $j$ we have $|B|=j.$ So let $B=\{B_y:y<j\}.$

For $S\in P(j)$ let $m^*(S)=m(\cup_{y\in S}B_y).$ We may confirm that $m^*:P(j)\to \{0,1\}$ is a non-trivial measure. But $j<k$ so this contradicts the minimality of $k.$

So there is no such $j$.

Therefore $I=m^{-1}\{0\}$ is a free (non-principal) maximal ideal on $k,$ and $\cup A\in I$ whenever $A\subset P(k)$ and $|A|<k,$ so $F= \{k\setminus i:i\in I\}$ is a free maximal filter  on $k,$ with $\cap C\in F$ whenever $C\subset F$ and $0<|C|<k.$

Remark: Regarding $m^*,$ if $S=\{S(n):n\in \omega\}\subset (m^*)^{-1}\{0\}$ then $S'=\{\cup_{y\in S(n)}B_y:n\in \omega\}\subset m^{-1}\{0\}, $ so $m^*(\cup S)=m(\cup S')=0.$